# need tsql code for time intervel and the values should go to that particular interval the original time is in epoch format

Tags: t-sql

I have to add column to table.
The column value is calculated based on the column already present in the table.

I have to get  time-stamp (column already present) and then group them into 5 min time-slots.

E.g: if the time is:

- 13:03/13:02 then it should go as 13:00;
- 13:53/13:52 then it should go as 13:50;
- 13:21 then should go as 13:20 and so on

PS: basically I have to get time stamp in epoch (UNIX time stamp)format [the table has values in epoch as well as in regular time stamp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table epoch1(epoch int not null,

epoch_date as dateadd(s,epoch,'19700101'))
insert epoch1(epoch) values(1331070999)
insert epoch1(epoch) values(1331070956)
insert epoch1(epoch) values(1331071998)
insert epoch1(epoch) values(1331071999)


select DATEADD(MINUTE,-DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,dateadd(MINUTE,epoch,'19700101')) % 5,dateadd(MINUTE,epoch,'19700101')) as human ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', DATEADD(MINUTE,-DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,dateadd(MINUTE,epoch,'19700101')) % 5,dateadd(MINUTE,epoch,'19700101'))) as timeinterval
from epoch1
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I'm seeing is that you have times and you need to round them down to the nearest 5 minute increment. Try this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (times TIME)

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES  ('13:03'),
        ('13:02'),
        ('13:53'),
        ('13:52'),
        ('13:21');

SELECT  times,
        DATEADD(MINUTE,-DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,times) % 5,times) five_minute_increments
FROM @table
```

Results:

```
times              five_minute_increments
----------------   ----------------------
13:03:00.0000000   13:00:00.0000000
13:02:00.0000000   13:00:00.0000000
13:53:00.0000000   13:50:00.0000000
13:52:00.0000000   13:50:00.0000000
13:21:00.0000000   13:20:00.0000000
```

### Epoch Version

```
DECLARE @epoch BIGINT;

--Epoch is the seconds since Jan 1,1970
SET @epoch = DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01','2015-04-01 12:06:00.000');

SELECT CAST(DATEADD(SECOND,@epoch - (@epoch %300),'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000') AS TIME) AS epochTimes
```

Results:

```
12:05:00.0000000
```

Comment: Since epoch is measured in seconds, it's modulus 300 seconds(five minutes), I then convert it to DATETIME so you can see the results

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free mark mine as the answer so other people know it works and that your question has been answered.